# Working function in python however my test still fails?

Tags: python, function

I am creating a function in python that identifies whether an ingredient is on a menu, the menu is inputted as strings. It has to pass the test code given below and although it is outputting the correct boolean the test is saying 'Failure'?
Here is my python function

```
def free_from(test_menu: str, str):
    if str in test_menu:
        print(False)
    else:
        print(True)
```

This is the test it has to pass

```
test_menu = [ ['potato'],
              ['cheese'],
              ['apple'] ]
expected_result = True
if free_from(test_menu, 'water') == expected_result:
    print('Working')
else:
    print('Failure')
```

It is outputting
True
Failure

Comment: You need to return True/False instead of printing.

Comment: Your function does not return anything, it only prints

Comment: Your function always returns `None`